# Drag&Drop dashed border

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, drag

Using this example http://jsfiddle.net/sPbmM/93/, i'm trying to make the border of ".cart" becomes dashed when drag element is over this. 
I tried with

```
.cart:hover{
    border: dashed }
```

and

```
$('.cart ').droppable({
       accept: ".drag",
   hoverclass: 'hover',
    drop: function(event, ui){       
        window.location=$(ui.draggable).find("a.addtocart").attr("href");
    }
});
```

without any results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the `hoverClass` option and then define in your CSS this class not the `hover` effect as you do in

```
.cart:hover{
    border: dashed }
```

Try:

```
$('.cart ').droppable({
       accept: ".drag",

    drop: function(event, ui){       
        window.location=$(ui.draggable).find("a.addtocart").attr("href");
    },
    hoverClass:"dashed"

});
```

And add in the CSS:

```
.dashed{
    border: 5px dashed #ccc;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sPbmM/97/)

Answer (score 1):

Use the hoverClass option of the droppable, with a big C:

```
hoverClass: "drop-hover",
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/sPbmM/98/

Answer (score 0):

Use the draggable's drag and stop to change the border style:

```
$('.drag').draggable({
    revert: "invalid",
    helper: "clone",
    drag: function () {
        $('div.cart').css('borderStyle', 'dashed')
    },
    stop: function () {
        $('div.cart').css('borderStyle', 'solid')
    }
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/sPbmM/96/)**

Alternately you could add and remove a class to modify the border. If you only want to apply the change when the item is over the cart, use the droppable's over and out events instead

```
$('.cart ').droppable({
    accept: ".drag",
    over: function () {
        $('div.cart').css('borderStyle', 'dashed');
    },
    out: function () {
        $('div.cart').css('borderStyle', 'solid');
    },
    drop: function (event, ui) {
        window.location = $(ui.draggable).find("a.addtocart").attr("href");
    }
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/sPbmM/99/)**